# pyrequests encoding dict values as lists in JSON

Tags: python, rest

I'm working on a Python client for a REST API, and i'm using [requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/quickstart/) to handle the communication with the server. When using the `post` method though, I get some weird behaviour.

Here is the code that sends the request:

```py
nombre = 'Daniel'
email  = 'foo@bar.baz'

object = {
    'nombre': nombre,
    'email': email
}

r = requests.post(some_url,
                  json=object)
```

Now I would expect the JSON in the request to be formatted something like

```
{"nombre": "Daniel", "email": "foo@bar.baz"}
```

However what I'm seeing in wireshark is

```
{"nombre": ["Daniel"], "email": ["foo@bar.baz"]}
```

Which the server obviously can't understand. I'm not sure if this is the intended behaviour of the library, but I don't think so. I could solve it by encoding manually to JSON but I feel like that shouldn't be necessary.

Comment: Perhaps, look for `object_pairs_hook` : https://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html#json.load

Comment: Do `r = requests.post('https://httpbin.org/post', json=object)` and see what the value of `r.json()['data']` is (httpbin just returns your data content back to you). When I do that with your example code above I get `'{"nombre": "Daniel", "email": "foo@bar.baz"}'`.

Comment: @SuperShoot I tried your answer, and I got the same result. However, I tried debugging some more and it turns out the problem was with how I was parsing the variables. The library I was using (argparse), put them into lists.

Comment: I guess my next question is, how do I close this one?

Comment: Glad you got it sorted out!

Comment: @Daniel do you mean how do you close the question? You can provide your own answer.

Answer (score -1):

Try this

```
 import json

 nombre = 'Daniel'
 email  = 'foo@bar.baz'

 object = {
   'nombre': nombre,
   'email': email
 }

  r = requests.post(some_url,
              json=json.dumps(object))
```

Comment: This is exactly what requests is doing under the hood anyway: https://github.com/kennethreitz/requests/blob/a345b776fb2cf67d1a1810349e71fd60a83f53eb/requests/models.py#L466